# Getting a indexPath.row with a matching value

Tags: swift, tableview

So, I have two Json requests from the same API with the difference, that one is from today and the other one from yesterday. I have them displayed in "MyCell" in my TableView and the result is this.

[image]
This is the code :

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        let today = today[indexPath.row]
        let yesterday = yesterday[indexPath.row]

        let nameOfThe place = today.local
        let salesToday = today.sales 

        let nameOfThePlaceYesterday = yesterday.local
        let salesYesterday = yesterday.sales


}
```

So far, so good. Thats whats I wanted. The problem start when some places havent open yesterday( for example A and B). I get this:

[image]

Whats happening is, since there isnt the same "numberOfRowsInSection" for both days, it just populates cell in order but mismatching places. Question: 
How do I get "indexPath.row" with a matching value of the other indexPath.row. In this case it would be a name of the place.

Thank you

Comment: See my last comment to your previous question

Comment: That didnt work.

Comment: Why not? Why shouldn't `let yesterday = yesterday.first(where: {$0.name = today.name})` work? I don't recommend that you reuse variable names like that, it will only make the code harder to read when you have a property `today` that is an array and a variable `today` that is an object from the array.

Comment: Can you show the JSON ?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson. Sorry for the late response. You were right, It did work at the end. Thank you soo much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        let today = today[indexPath.row]
        let nameOfThe place = today.local
        let salesToday = today.sales 

        if let yesterday = yesterday[safe: indexPath.row] {
           let nameOfThePlaceYesterday = yesterday.local
           let salesYesterday = yesterday.sales
        }
}
```